# Usage of "against"

Tags: word-usage, word-request

What word is more preferable (or even correct) in following context:

> Application is locked **against** modifications.

or

> Application is locked **from** modifications.

Or, may be, both usage (`against` and `from`) are correct)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My intuition says *against* is better than *from*.

However, I was surprised when I checked out what people really use in books. It seems like both (*against* and *from*) could be used. Here are some sentences I found:

> - *If the application is locked **against** change, however, the Options menu cannot be installed, ...*
> - *That system'Il be locked up against any move I try to make.
>     In Lock Read mode, the file is locked **against** others reading it.*
> - *... (although it can't hurt and might help to avoid keeping the file uselessly “locked" **against** modification in some operating systems and settings).*
> - *Processes that attempt to read or write a file region locked **against** reading and writing by another ...*
> - *The application is locked **from** the user until the printing process completes.*
> - *In essence, your application is locked **from** closing completely until all of its shared objects are no longer needed in any other client application.*
> - *Individual data items or sets of data are locked **from** concurrent access if they are involved in a transaction.*
> - *When a templatized file is locked **from** an edit, both the generated page and the data content record (DCR) are locked.*

However, when I tried searching for `locked * changes` and `locked * access` on [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=locked+%2a+modifications%2Clocked+%2a+modification%2Clocked+%2a+access%2Clocked+%2a+changes&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2Clocked%20%2a%20access%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Blocked%20and%20access%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Blocked%20against%20access%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clocked%20against%20changes%3B%2Cc0), it's clear that the normal usage is "locked against changes (or access)", which confirms my intuition.

So, I believe that you could use either (*locked against modifications* or *locked from modifications*); though if I had to choose, I would choose *against*. However, if I may, I'd like to suggest these instead:

> This application is locked, and no unauthorized modifications can be made.
>
> This application is locked to prevent unauthorized modifications.<sup>1</sup>
>   <sup>1) This sentence was suggested by Nice in our chat room. All credits go to him.</sup>

Also note that we should write a determiner *this* or the article *the*, depending on the context, before the word *application*.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if the second one is incorrect, but

> Application is locked against modifications.

[against, sense 1](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/against) is better because "locked" and "modifications" have opposite meanings. When its locked you can't do modifications.

Also you may wish to say "The application..." depending on the context.